# How to connect to a remote API from an web app running on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I am facing a strange problem. I have a mvc web application developed and running on my local machine and can connect to an API `https://api-uat1.%domain%.com:443` from the [api_root] configured as an app setting in the web config. But this is on my local.

Now i publish this app on Azure with the same connection string in the Application settings option in the blade and also the web config.

But this says the remote host not found when i run the application from Azure.

Are there any extra settings we need to do in Azure portal to register this remote host `https://api-uat1.%domain%.com:443`

Comment: Is that hostname available on public DNS?

Comment: Hello. junnas  sorry..what is public DNS? Do we have to configure anywhere in azure portal? Actually, this DNS name is carry forwarded from the old classic portal. I have migrated the solution from the old classic portal to the new ARM portal. This url works from the old classic portal.

Comment: Are you sure this error you are getting from this API call ?

Comment: Hello Mohamed...this is the exact error i am getting  System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'api.uat1.<domain>.com' 
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult) 
at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)

Comment: Is there a way to debug using the SOAP UI or postman APP?

Comment: It sounds like the hostname you are using is an internal hostname. The app in Azure is using public DNS servers to try and find where that API is based on the hostname, but is unable to. You'd need to either: a) get the hostname in public DNS, b) somehow get it to resolve it from private DNS

Comment: Thanks junnas...but if thats the case then how come i am able to connect to API from my local dev machine and perform the get operation successfully?

Comment: On second thoughts...how do we get the hostname in public DNS?